# I want to create a program that returns a list that contains only the elements that are common between the lists (without duplicates)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Below is the code:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
c = []

cal = len(a)


for d in range(cal):
     if a[d] in b and a[d] not in c:
         c.append(a[d])
print(c)
```

Below is the output:

[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]

Process finished with exit code 0

I was not able to make the logic myself so I had looked at the solution but still didn't get the concept behind the code. The point where I am getting confused is that in cal I am storing the length of a which is 11, then I am doing a for loop 11 times(I am not sure why this is being done and what will we get from this part), then then finally conditional using "a[d]". It just doesnt makes sense to me.

Comment: I think it might help to clarify your question: do you want an explanation for *this* code, or do you want a better way to do it?  If you just want a better way, this question is a duplicate of several already on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's break done the code

```
range(integer_value)
```

Returns a list of elements from 0 to integer_value -1 that's why you can iter over it

with this said:

```
#this is returning the longitude of the list
cal = len(a) 
#this is iterating over a list of [0,1,2,3... until len -1)
for d in range(cal):
    #this checks if the value of a in the position d is in the list called b
    #this is also checking that it's not in c to avoid duplication,
    #but you could use a set which is a "list" that doesn't accept duplicates
    if a[d] in b and a[d] not in c:
         c.append(a[d])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could even use a set

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

c = filter(set(a).__contains__, b)
print(list(c))
# [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy peasy...

```
c = [i for i in set(a) if i in b]
```

the `set(a)` call eliminates any dups in the first list, and that takes care of the entire answer.  This uses what's known as "list comprehension," which makes for very concise but powerful code.

Answer (score 1):

Let's expand the ideas into English:

```
for each of the 11 positions in a:
     grab the element in that position ...
     if that element is also in b (so it's in both a and b),
         but is not yet in c (so we get no duplicates):

         add it to c
```

Does that clear up the logic for you?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly this code is logically incorrect if you plan on perhaps changing these lists.

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
c = []

cal = min(len(a),len(b))

for d in range(cal):
     if a[d] in b and a[d] not in c:
         c.append(a[d])
print(c)
```

We are checking in the for loop that the element at index d, which takes on every value from 0 to 11, if the element at a[d], which is the dth element in a, is also in b. If it is in b, and already has not been added to the list c, then we add it.

One can do this in many syntactically better ways:

```
c = list(set([d for a in d if d in b]))
```

or

```
c = filter(set(a).__contains__, b)
```

or

```
c = list(set(a).union(b))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
c = []

c = list( set(a).intersection(set(b)) )
print (c)
```

The code is self explanatory given that you have basic knowledge of sets.

Answer (score 1):

what you are doing is to compare list a with the elements of list b.

only if an element of list a is also in list b, you put it into the list c.

list c will contain all matching numbers of list a and b, which is obviously the case.

About the comparison which seam to confusing you:

you have to loop 11 times because the len of list a is 11. if you want to compare every element of list a with list b you have to do this.

```
for d in range(cal):
```

means you get a range of numbers from 0 to the value of cal (which is the len of your list a), in this case 0,1,2,...10.

```
a[d]
```

then means

```
a[0]
a[1]
...
a[10]
```

so you finally iterate over every element of your list.

hope that helps your understanding.

Best,

me

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

my_list = random.sample(range(1,30), 10)
my_list.sort()

my_list2 = random.sample(range(1,40), 15)
my_list2.sort()

print(my_list)
print()
print(my_list2)
print()

common = []

for i in my_list:
            if i in my_list2:
            common.append(i)

print(common)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]  
c = [x for x in set(a) if x in set(b)]
print c
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

Comment: this contains duplicates

Comment: It is removing duplicates, as I used "and"

Comment: b = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13] introduces a second 1 into the list c.